# How to build custom docker images with a specific network?

Tags: docker

While building custom images (like extending the cm) I've seen various networking issues when on VPN. I noticed that containers can reach the internet with `docker compose up` but the same resources can't be reached during build.

Is there way way to specify a custom network when building images in `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few observations I've made while working over VPN (in particular Palo Global Protect):

- Container networking appears to get disrupted when the VPN disconnects. Tearing down the containers with `docker compose down` and then `docker compose up -d` appears to correct the issue. I think this is because a new network is created which doesn't conflict with the VPN.
- The running containers use the new network which may be why containers can reach the internet.
- Building containers use the default network. Creating a new network and associating it with the build would create a similar scenario as the running containers.

Start by creating a new `build.ps1`:

```
param(
    [string[]]$Services
)

$networkResult = docker network inspect build-nat | ConvertFrom-Json
if(!$networkResult) {
    docker network create --driver nat build-nat
}
docker compose -f .\docker-compose.build.yml build $Services
docker network rm build-nat
```

Add the network to your build section in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
node:
  image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-node:${VERSION}
  build:
    context: ./docker/build/node
    network: build-nat
    args:
      BASE_IMAGE: ${NODE_BASE_IMAGE}
      NODE_VERSION: ${NODE_VERSION}
```